# OctoberCMS Ajax Form still Submits after pressing Cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](http://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

I have an [Ajax](http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction) checkbox form that uses [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) markup.

http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction

---

When you click the Delete button, it prompts with a popup asking to confirm. But if I press cancel, it still submits. However this was working before I switched to Twig/Ajax, but I need that to handle requests a regular form can't do.

```
{{ form_open() }}

    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_queued[]" value="{{ record.name }}" />

    <button data-request="onDelete" onclick="return confirm('Delete All Checked?');return false;">Delete Checked</button>

{{ form_close() }}
```

Note: `data-request="onDelete"` is a php function, it works fine. It's the `onclick` that is not working correctly.

---

I have tried to use the function outside of `onclick`, with same result:

`<button data-request="onDelete" onclick="confirmDelete()">Delete Checked</button>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete() {
        if (confirm("Delete All Checked?")) {
            //submit php data-request
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried to use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be because you're mixing the Data attributes API and the JavaScript API.

Instead, pick one and it should work:

```
{{ form_open() }}

    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_queued[]" value="{{ record.name }}" />

    <button data-request="onDelete" data-request-confirm="Delete All Checked?">Delete Checked</button>

{{ form_close() }}
```

Comment: That was it. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple `onClick="return confirm('Delete All Checked?');"`

Comment: It brings up the confirm popup, but if I press cancel it still submits.

Comment: move data-request="onDelete" to form tag instead of button.